# How can I create custom trips via Google Maps API in Rails and then store them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps

I'm making a web application in Rails 4 that is going to allow users to create trips.  These trips are going to be built dynamically using Google Maps API based upon user input. IE, users can create different waypoints and locations that they visited. I want users to be able to add waypoints and descriptions about particular stops.

But I want these locations to be stored so that there's a search function where users can search for different regions such as around a particular address or state.

I'm not looking for anything overly specific here, I just want an idea of how to set it up.

What I've thought of so far is that Users create trips which have many waypoints that in turn are models.  I'm not sure that is ideal however.

Thoughts?  Even a link to a post I might have missed is helpful. Thanks.

Edit: In case anyone runs across this problem in the future.  I went with Google Map's Directions API.  It lets you pass in waypoints as an array of objects.  I used JavaScript to add waypoints as necessary and then allowed the user to submit to how the map looked.  Then, if they liked it, they submitted the trip form which logged the input values into the db as attributes to the trip object.